# Remove pop out option in google drive/doc viewer in webview android

Tags: android

Remove pop out option in google drive/doc viewer in webview android

I need to view pdf in webview , the user cant able to save irt so hide all options

Answer (score -1):

```
//initialze WebView
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullscree_webview);

//set the javascript enable to your webview
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//set the WebViewClient
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

//once the page is loaded get the html element by class or id and through javascript hide it.
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        }
    })
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining exactly how it solves the problem in the original question.  Code-only answers are not very useful because it puts a large burden on readers to try and understand which part is most important.

Comment: @William Price please run the above code ..... Hope my brief explanation cleared your doubt